# Getting 404 when deploying war file to JBoss 7.1

Tags: jboss, http-status-code-404, war, jboss7.x

I'm using JBoss 7.1.0 AS on Mac OSX Lion.  I'm having trouble figuring out why one of my artifacts isn't deploying.  I copied my war file to the $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments directory.  When I login to the JBoss admin console, it tells me my war file (named "eventmaven.war") is enabled.  However, when I visit http://localhost:8080/eventmaven, I get the 404 error page saying

```
The requested resource (/eventmaven/) is not available.
```

There is nothing in my logs (located in $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/log/server.log or $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/log/boot.log) to indicate why I'm getting this 404.  Can anyone think of a reason or suggest additional steps for troubleshooting?

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 2):

Try to access a file that you know exists, like say a jpg or gif file. The above could be caused if you do not have a welcome page setup correctly.

Comment: I created a directory $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments/test and within it, placed an image, example.jpg.  However, when I visit http://localhost:8080/test/example.jpg, I get a 404.  What does it mean?

Comment: Does anything work at all ? Does localhost:8080 return anything ? Try using the hostname instead of localhost.

Answer (score 0):

In JBoss 7 you should create a file in the deployments directory named .dodeploy to trigger deployment.

`eventmaven.dodeploy` in your case.